# Overlay two alluvial plots with same dimensions

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I am trying to plot rectangle on top of an alluvial plot in R. 
my codes are:

```
library(alluvial)
tit <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
tit2d <- aggregate(Freq ~ Class + Survived, data=tit, sum)


alluvial(tit2d, freq = tit2d$Freq, xw = 0.0, alpha = 0.8,
         gap.width = 0.1, col = "steelblue", border = "white",
         layer = tit2d$Survived != "Yes", blocks = F)

par(new = TRUE) 
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
rect(0, 0, 0.3, 0.4, col = "red")
```

**But How do I make sure that the coordinates of both the plots are same, as my rectangle is based on the alluvial coordinates?**

Comment: You can check the axis limits using `par("usr")` immediately after calling the `alluvial` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the par("usr") command can tell you the extremes of the current plotting region. But it's a bit difficult here because the alluvial function adjusts the `mar` graphics parameter within the function. It changes the margins to `c(2,1,1,1)`. At the end of the function it reverts the margins back to what they were initially. The default margins are c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1 representing the number of lines (1 line = 1/5 inches) between the bottom, left, top, and right outer margins to the plotting region. Look at help page for `par` and scroll down until you get to mai to see a good diagram. Another adjustment made by the alluvial function is to change the default *style* of the axes from regular (xaxs="r", yaxs="r") to internal (xaxs="i", yaxs="i"), which causes the axes to extend a little further.

For example:

```
alluvial( tit2d, freq=tit2d$Freq, xw=0.0, alpha=0.8,
                gap.width=0.1, col= "steelblue", border="white",
                layer = tit2d$Survived != "Yes", blocks = F )

u <- par("usr"); u
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(0, type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", las=1, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", 
xlim=c(u[1], u[2]), ylim=c(u[3], u[4]))
rect(u[1], u[3], u[2], u[4], col = "red")
```

You'll get a red rectangle filling in most of the plot region. The large gaps between the rectangle extremes and the the alluvial extremes is due to the said change in the margins.

You can try to imitate the alluvial function by manually reducing the margins as follows:

```
op <- par(mar=c(2,1,1,1))
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(0, type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", las=1, 
     xlim=c(u[1], u[2]), ylim=c(u[3], u[4]))
rect(u[1], u[3], u[2], u[4], col = "green")
par(op)
```

Your green rectangle should now cover the whole alluvial plot.

**Edit**:
To highlight the lower rectangles:

```
par(new=TRUE, mar=c(2,1,1,1)) 
u <- par("usr")
rect(u[1], temp$endpoints[[1]][1,1], u[1]+0.2, # Note: cw has a default value of 0.1
   temp$endpoints[[1]][1,2], col = "red")

rect(u[1]+1, temp$endpoints[[1]][1,1], u[1]+1.2, 
   temp$endpoints[[1]][1,2], col = "red")

rect(u[1]+2, temp$endpoints[[1]][1,1], u[1]+2.2, 
   temp$endpoints[[1]][1,2], col = "red")
```

**Edit**: Thanks to @Darren Tsai for pointing out that low-level plotting functions such as `rect()` do not have a "xaxs" argument for modifying the axis style, since the axes are already there!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Let's say i store the result of the plot in a variable called **temp**. The variable will store the endpoints of the plot which is basically the coordinates. if I want to highlight the lower-left rectangle, I fetch the coordinates and draw the plot  ```rect(0,temp$endpoints[[1]][1,1],.3,temp$endpoints[[1]][1,2],col = "red") ``` it doesn't work

Comment: ```temp= alluvial( tit2d, freq=tit2d$Freq, xw=0.0, alpha=0.8,
                gap.width=0.1, col= "steelblue", border="white",
                layer = tit2d$Survived != "Yes",blocks = F ) ```

Comment: See edit. You need to modify the plotting margins (`mar=c(2,1,1,1`) and the axis _style_ as mentioned in my answer: (xaxs="i", yaxs="i"). Remember, that's what the alluvial function is doing (__secretly__).

Comment: `xaxs = "i"` and `yaxs = "i"` belong to high-level graphical parameters. I think they make no sense in low-level function `rect()`.

Comment: @Darren Tsai... You're quite right. Thanks for noticing that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can think *Why does this function return only matrices of y-coordinates of endpoints?* 
 From the document of `alluvial`, it says:

> x-coordinates are consecutive **natural numbers**.

**Explanation**

In your example, there are three pillars in the plot, and that means their **midpoints** are located at 1, 2, 3 respectively. However, where are the left and right bounds of each pillar? I think you ignored a crucial argument `cw` of `alluvial()`, which controls the width of pillars. If you don't set it, it'll take its default value `0.1`. The left and right bounds of each pillar will be

[image]

Now you can easily find both bounds of eanch pillar.

```
temp <- alluvial(tit2d, freq = tit2d$Freq, xw = 0, alpha = 0.8,
                 gap.width = 0.1, col = "steelblue", border = "white",
                 layer = tit2d$Survived != "Yes", blocks = F)

par(xpd = TRUE)
abline(v = 1:3, lwd = 3, col = "red")
abline(v = 1:3 - 0.1, lwd = 3, col = "blue")
abline(v = 1:3 + 0.1, lwd = 3, col = "green")
```

[image]

If you want to highlight a certain rectangle:

```
par(xpd = TRUE)
y <- temp$endpoints

# bottom-left rectangle
rect(1 - 0.1, y[[1]][1, 1],
     1 + 0.1, y[[1]][1, 2], col = "red")

# the second pillar, the fourth rectangle from the bottom
rect(2 - 0.1, y[[2]][4, 1],
     2 + 0.1, y[[2]][4, 2], col = "orange")
```

[image]

---

**Why `par(xpd = TRUE)`?**

`par("xpd")` can be set

- `FALSE`(default): all plotting is clipped to the "plot" region
- `TRUE`: all plotting is clipped to the "figure" region
- `NA`: all plotting is clipped to the "device" region

If you don't change the default value, all the low-level plotting functions, e.g. `points()`, `abline()`, `rect()`, `text()`..., will be clipped when out of the "plot" region. You can use `box()` to see where the "plot" region is.

---

**Conclusion**

1. Argument `cw = 0.1` (the default). You can change it, but x-coordinates will be different.
2. Set `par(xpd = TRUE)`.

---

**Supplement**

If you want to change the order of drawing of the stripes, try to adjust the argument `layer`. It can be a logical or numeric vector. The larger the number is, the earlier the stripe is drawn, that is, it'll be lower than the stripe of smaller numbers.

In your example, you can change the order according to the rank of `Freq`.
Note the difference of the following:

- `rank(tit2d$Freq)` map smaller values to lower ranks.
- `rank(-tit2d$Freq)` map smaller values to upper ranks.

```
tit2d$Freq
# [1] 122 167 528 673 203 118 178 212

rank(tit2d$Freq)
# [1] 2 3 7 8 5 1 4 6

rank(-tit2d$Freq)
# [1] 7 6 2 1 4 8 5 3
```

Therefore, what you require in the comment is the latter.

```
alluvial(tit2d, freq = tit2d$Freq, xw = 0, alpha = 0.8,
         gap.width = 0.1, col = "steelblue", border = "white",
         layer = rank(-tit2d$Freq), blocks = F)
```

[image]

Comment: Very detailed answer. Can you also let me know how to change the order of lines in the alluvial. Like if i want the line of 673 to be on top of 212 (in the last column) . How do i do that?

Comment: @DhwaniDholakia see my edit. I add the supplementary part.

Comment: the explanation that you added now has so much of information in addition to answering my question. It covers much more details even than the manual of alluvial. Many thanks for your effort.